# Why my android app isn't responding after POST method?

Tags: android, node.js, json, post, httpurlconnection

I have a problem. I'm trying to execute POST method to my Node.js server. After POST method I'm getting all the data in server but then my app isn't responding a few seconds. Is there some bugs in my code?

My POST method:

```
public static void setTemp(String address, String hot, String cold) throws IOException
    {
        URL url = new URL(address); //in the real code, there is an ip and a port
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        try {
            conn.connect();

            JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
            jsonParam.put("hot", hot);
            jsonParam.put("cold", cold);

            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());

            os.flush();
            os.close();

            Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
            Log.i("MSG" , conn.getResponseMessage());

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

This is how I call the POST method:

```
    private void setTemp(String hot, String cold)
    {
        try {
            WebAPI.setTemp(Tools.RestURLPost, hot, cold);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And here you can find my Node.js method which I use to test successful parsing of JSON:

```
router.post('/post', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

Comment: I suppose you're running in a background thread right? I don't know it's possible anymore to run a network request in the main thread, but it's been a few years since I code anything using Android SDK

Comment: Your node.js route does not send any response so the client code is still sitting there waiting for a response.  At least add `res.send("ok")` or `res.json({status: "ok"})` to the node.js route.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the whole code it's hard to know but you're never ending the request in Node, so use: `req.send/json`, otherwise the Android application will wait until the request is done, which won't happen and it will timeout.

```
router.post('/post', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.json({ success: true });
});
```

Comment: You might also want to output or log errors in your Android app when you catch them.